# How to embed JyNI in a jar

Tags: java, maven, numpy, jar, jython

I'm developing an application in java, and in this one, I use [jython-standalone](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.1) (Jython for untold reasons, its goal being to ease some scripting within the application).

I would like to have access to NumPy, and it seems that [JyNI](https://jyni.org) provides such capabilities.

I found many posts explaining how to start a Jython project using JyNI, but none on how to include the .jar or something in the application so that it is available when needed.

As stated on [JyNI](https://github.com/Stewori/JyNI#3-installing-jyni), `java -cp build/JyNI.jar -jar jython.jar` does not work.

Is there a way for me to use JyNI when executing some Jython code through a [PythonInterpreter](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start the live interpreter by executing the class org.python.util.jython.

On Linux, OSX:

```
java -cp jython.jar:build/JyNI.jar org.python.util.jython
```

On Windows:

```
java -cp jython.jar;build\JyNI.jar org.python.util.jython
```

Alternatively, one can use Jython's start script:

```
jython -J-cp build/JyNI.jar
```

This info is taken from https://github.com/Stewori/JyNI#running-jyni, but leaving out the script argument someFile.py.

If you want to explicitly leverage the interpreter through Java code, you will surely have some way to launch your overall application. Make sure to have JyNI.jar and the folder containing its binaries on classpath in that command. Jython should be running with JyNI support then.

A side-note: Be sure to use Jython 2.7.1 and NumPy >= 1.12. Version mismatch of these prerequisites is a common cause of failure.

Comment: Can JyNI be included as a maven dependency in a maven based java application.

Comment: No, not at the moment. I plan to figure this out when JyNI reaches beta state. Currently there are more acute issues to work on than Maven integration.

Comment: @stewori  Is there a way, it could be configured in eclipse? I already have PyDev for eclipse and can create Jython2.7.1 project in eclipse. To make use pandas library in jython project, I downloaded the JyNI.jar from https://github.com/Stewori/JyNI/releases/tag/v2.7-alpha.5  . Added jar by Rt. click on project>properties>PyDev - PYTHONPATH and under External Libraries. But on run of my simple panda prog, I get error "console: Failed to install '': java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cp0. Can't find library file: JyNI.dll".  Any thoughts on this and how to use JyNI.jar in eclipse